# Flutter Build Error - Issues with Kotlin Gradle Plugin

Tags: flutter, kotlin, dart, build

I'm facing an issue when trying to build my Flutter app in VS Code. Here are the details of my environment and the error:

- **Operating System:** Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
- **IDE:** Visual Studio Code
- **Flutter Version:** 3.13.2
- **Flutter Doctor Output:**

  ```
  [✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.13.2, on Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS 6.2.0-34-generic, locale pt_BR.UTF-8)
  [✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
  [✓] Chrome - develop for the web
  [✓] Linux toolchain - develop for Linux desktop
  [✓] Android Studio (version 2022.3)
  [!] Android Studio (version unknown)
      ✗ Unable to determine Android Studio version.
  [✓] VS Code (version unknown)
      ✗ Unable to determine VS Code version.
  [✓] Connected device (2 available)
  [✓] Network resources

  ! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
  ```
- **Build Error:**

  ```
  [!] Your project requires a newer version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin.
  Find the latest version on https://kotlinlang.org/docs/releases.html#release-details, then update
  /home/anderson/www_IE/monitorie_thingsboard/android/build.gradle:
  ext.kotlin_version = '<latest-version>'
  ```

[Print of terminal error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzVcq.png)

- **Additional Information:**

  - I tried changing the Kotlin version from 1.7.10 to 1.7.21 and 1.9.10, but the error persists.
  - I attempted to update `gradlew` manually with the following commands, but it didn't work:

    ```
    ./gradlew wrapper --gradle-version 7.5.1
    ./gradlew --version
    ./gradlew build
    ```
  - I also tried altering the `classpath` configuration in the `build.gradle` file.
  - I made changes to the GitHub repository.
  - I added a `.env` file to enhance the security of sensitive data.

The app is signed with the Google certificate for Play Store publication. If I generate a new certificate, I can build it, but I can't upload it.

I'm seeking assistance to resolve this issue and allow my app to be built successfully. Any suggestions or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!